# Система событий на c++

Tags: c++

Подскажите оптимальный способ для реализации событий на `C++`.
Нужно реализовать подписку на события, с возможностью передачи аргументов. Такая система есть в `Node JS(https://metanit.com/web/nodejs/2.9.php)`.

Например, есть объект класса `Player`, в этом классе содержится функция `OnConnected`.
К примеру, я хочу установить слушатель на эту функцию:   `EventManager.subscribe(object, OnConnected, функция-слушатель c аргументами)`.
При вызове функции `OnConnected` должна вызываться функция-слушатель с аргументами.

Comment: не понятно в каком котексте задается вопрос. Что за события?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch , например есть объект класса Player, в этом классе содержится функция OnConnected . К примеру, я хочу установить слушатель на эту функцию: EventManager.subscribe(object, OnConnected, функция-слушатель c аргументами). При вызове функции OnConnected должна вызываться функция-слушатель с аргументами

Comment: Вряд ли (в том виде, как вы описываете) это можно реализовать в общем случае. Довольно очевидна реализация, когда сама `onConnected()` запрограммирована так, что она знает о списке слушателей и сама вызывает их. Другой вариант -- существует 3-я функция, которая управляет списками слушателей. При ее вызове  передаем ссылку на `onConnected()` и она вызовет ее, а затем всех слушателей. Такие вещи понятно, как можно сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Это скорее сигналы, нежели события. Могу посоветовать `boost` (сам не использовал тамошние сигналы) или `Qt` (в ней  система сигналов-слотов довольно хорошая, НО имеет достаточно подводных камней и требует метакомпилятор)

Comment: Плохая идея использовать такие большие библиотеки ради небольшой фичи

Comment: Добавил ссылку на пример в node js

Comment: @Dmirty какие "библиотеки"? 1) чтобы юзать бустовые сигналы не нужен весь `boost`! 2) про минус `Qt` я и так упомянул. 3) Кто вам сказал, что это простая фича?

Answer (score 0):

Можно реализовать шаблон `Observer` (при помощи него, в частности, реализована система событий в Java).

Создаем интерфейс для слушателей событий в классе `Player`:

```
class IPlayerEventsListener {
protected:
    virtual void onConnected(/*Необходимые аргументы*/) {};
}
```

С его помощью мы будем регистрировать и слушать события нашего Игрока:

```
class Player {
public:
    explicit Player() : _listener(nullptr) {}

    void setListener(IPlayerEventsListener* listener) {
        _listener = listener;
    }

    void onConnected() {
        // Логика
        // А теперь сообщаем о данном событии слушателю
        if( _listener != nullptr ) {
            _listener.onConnected(/*Что-то передаем*/);
        }
    }

private:
    IPlayerEventsListener* _listener;
}
```

Теперь, чтобы начать слушать объекты класса `Player` надо наследовать и реализовать соответствующий интерфейс "снаружи":

```
class SomePlayerListener : public IPlayerEventsListener {
public:
    void onConnected(/*Необходимые аргументы*/) override {
        //реагируем на событие, например пишем логи куда надо
    }
}
```

Регистрируем слушатель в игроке:

```
// Где-то, на просторах нашего кода
SomePlayerListener playerListener;

Player player;
player.setListener(&playerListener);
```

Можно реализовать класс посредник `EventManager`, который будет осуществлять данную операцию:

```
class EventManager {
public:
    static void subscribe(Player& player /*events provider*/, 
                          IPlayerEventsListener& listener /*subscriber*/) {
        // если надо, то что-то проверяем
        // регистрируем
        player.setListener(&listener);
    }

}
```